# Is there a CSS 'content-visibility' alternative / polyfill for older browsers?

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, optimization, performance-testing

I was checking this new `content-visibility` CSS property that was introduced in Chrome 85 that apparently boosts rendering performance in a webpage. [Link for the article here](https://web.dev/content-visibility/)

I was wondering if something like this already existed, how good this is compared to lazyloading and any advice on using it

Comment: `content-visibility` is more about saving rendering cycles than it is about loading speed; lazyloading still has the element there and in memory, but just hasn't loaded the content yet. The closest equivalent for old browsers is likely just having something not in the DOM and then inserting/appending it when needed.